# How to match exactly digit '1' preceeded or followed by any number if 0's?

Tags: bash, grep

The output contains only 0's and 1's. It should have exactly single '1' digit proceeded or followed by any number of 0's. I tried below regex - it finds ending zeroes but fails to filter preceding non-zero values. (see failing cases below).

```
# echo 00000000020000000000010000000000 | grep -E "0{1,}+10{8,}0$"
00000000020000000000010000000000 #not ok
# echo 6C740100000000000000000000000000 | grep -E "0{1,}+10{8,}0$"
6C740100000000000000000000000000 #not ok
# echo 0001000100000000000000000000000000 | grep -E "0{1,}+10{8,}0$"
0001000100000000000000000000000000 #not ok
# echo 0000000100000000000000000000000000 | grep -E "0{1,}+10{8,}0$"
0000000100000000000000000000000000 #ok
```

I'm missing something very basic. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overthinking it.

```
echo "..." | grep '^0*10*$'
```

The `^` and `$` ensure you are matching the entire line, not just a substring in the middle. `0*` is zero or more 0s; `1` is self-explanatory :).

Comment: Yes, you are correct :) Will accept this as answer in few minutes once SO allows me to do so.  thanks for the help :D